# How to increase obj.ttl in Varnish vcl_backend_error

Tags: varnish

Since you still might have this cumbersome backend that isn't very friendly to work with you might want to increase obj.ttl in Varnish 4.x . Like this:

```
sub vcl_backend_response{
    if(beresp.http.X-Response-Error == '1'){
        set obj.ttl = 120s;
        return (abandon);
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

But obj could not be accessed in vcl_backend_response.
Is there any other way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Grace Mode](https://www.varnish-software.com/book/3/Saving_a_request.html). When Varnish is in grace mode, it uses an object that has already expired as far as the TTL is concerned.

I used [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleGrace) as base and adapted it to Varnish 4.0

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #This is in case you have configured probe.
  if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    set req.grace = 30s;
  } else {
    set req.grace = 1h;
  }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  set beresp.grace = 1h;
}
```

**tl;dr (grace mode link)**

- A graced object is an object that has expired, but is still kept in cache.
- Grace mode is when Varnish uses a graced object.
- req.grace defines how long overdue an object can be for Varnish to still consider it for grace mode.
- beresp.grace defines how long past the beresp.ttl-time Varnish will keep an object
- req.grace is often modified in vcl_recv based on the state of the backend.